# SUM table by DAYNAME and name while having time inteval

Tags: mysql

I have this table called "downloads" composed like this

```
id  date                name                                      quantity
 1  2015-05-13 23:30:09 CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03                1
 2  2015-05-14 00:30:09 CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01       1
 3  2015-05-14 17:10:06 CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03                1
 4  2015-05-15 23:47:07 CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01       1
 5  2015-05-16 03:31:06 CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03                1
 6  2015-05-17 13:13:06 CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03                1
 7  2015-05-18 00:32:06 CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01       1
```

I want to `SUM` all the `"name"` by `DAYNAME` while having an interval `DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` .
Also the sum to be name aware

Currenty what I have is this

```
SELECT name, SUM(quantity), DAYNAME(d.date) AS weekday 

    FROM downloads d
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(d.date)

/*// This does not work I get a fetch_assoc error also does not have a time interval
    SELECT WEEKDAY(d.date) AS weekday,
             SUM(CASE WHEN d.name = 'CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a,
             SUM(CASE WHEN d.name = 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b,
        FROM downloads d
    GROUP BY WEEKDAY(d.date) */
```

I get this kind of mixed result without interval

```
Monday - CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03 - 70
Tuesday - CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01 - 72
Wednesday - CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03 - 89
Thursday - CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03 - 77
Friday - CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03 - 70
Saturday - CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03 - 68
Sunday - CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01 - 49
```

Thank you for anyone carrying to help

Comment: What are your expected results giving that sample data?

Comment: You've shown the results that you didn't want, but without seeing how you want the results, it will be hard to help you write this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of times each name appears for each weekday, you can use the aggregation you already have, but group by both name and weekday:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(dateColumn) AS weekDay, name, SUM(quantity) AS totalCount
FROM downloads
GROUP BY DAYNAME(dateColumn), name;
```

To only select on an interval, you can just add a where clause. For example, if I wanted to do this only for the month of may:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(dateColumn) AS weekDay, name, SUM(quantity) AS totalCount
FROM downloads
WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31'
GROUP BY DAYNAME(dateColumn), name;
```

If you want to see the names side by side, with each row for a weekday, you need to look into a pivot table, which is hard to do. However, if you know the row names, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(dateColumn) AS weekday,
  SUM(name = 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01') AS 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01',
  SUM(name = 'CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03') AS 'CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03'
FROM downloads
WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31'
GROUP BY DAYNAME(dateColumn);
```

Both queries can be seen in action at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9a54/8).

Comment: Thank you it works, but I had to change `WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB( now() , INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND NOW()`

Comment: @Alex_TNT that makes sense. I just used the month because that is what worked with your data, and will continue to work for people who stumble upon this. `NOW()` only works today ;P